# (Javascript) Determine if a numbervalue is contained or a number less than the numbervalue is contained in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects with arrays of consecutive integers, and an integer value:

```js
const worlds = [
{levelnumbers: [0,1,2,3,4,5]},
{levelnumbers: [6,7,8,9,10]},
{levelnumbers: [11,12,13,14]}];

const reachedLevel = 9;
```

I want to determine if `reachedLevel` or a value lower than that is contained in each world object and set a locked value on each object.

I have tried this:

```js
worlds.forEach(world => {
world.locked = !world.levelnumbers.includes(reachedLevel);
}
);
```

But is "locks" all worlds but the one containing the actual reached level. I want worlds[0] to have locked set to false even though levelReached is eg. 10.

Comment: do you have a result of the wanted?

Comment: I always mix up contains with includes... so I meant includes - the casing typos is just typos as I didn't copy/paste any code.

Comment: Seems you got it already @NinaScholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look to the minimum of the numbers and check against your value.

```js
const
    worlds = [{ levelNumbers: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, { levelNumbers: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }, { levelNumbers: [11, 12, 13, 14] }],
    reachedLevel = 9;

worlds.forEach(world => world.locked = Math.min(...world.levelNumbers) > reachedLevel);

console.log(worlds);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if all level numbers are greater than the reached level using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and assign the result to the `locked` parameter.

```js
const worlds = [
  {levelNumbers: [0,1,2,3,4,5]},
  {levelNumbers: [6,7,8,9,10]},
  {levelNumbers: [11,12,13,14]}
];

const reachedLevel = 9;

worlds.forEach(world => 
  world.locked = world.levelNumbers.every(n => n > reachedLevel) 
)

console.log(worlds);
```

Answer (score 0):

First , check your javascript object. it contains `levelnumbers` and `levelNumbers` and both are not same.

Second -  Instead of `contains` use `include` and what is `contains` though?

```js
const worlds = [
{levelnumbers: [0,1,2,3,4,5]},
{levelnumbers: [6,7,8,9,10]},
{levelnumbers: [11,12,13,14]}];

const reachedLevel = 9;

worlds.forEach(world => {
  world.locked = world.levelnumbers.includes(reachedLevel)
}
);

console.log(worlds);
```

Comment: "*Instead of contains use include and what is contains though?*" it's the name of the method originally proposed for this functionality. However, the MooTools library had already changed the native prototypes to add their own version of `contains` which was incompatible with the ES proposal. The result was that `contains` propoasal was changed to `includes`. [See here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible). Firefox also uses adds a (now) non-standard `contains` method to arrays but it shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: Informative. So we might have ended up using `contains` instead of `includes` and `contains` make better sense though.

Answer (score -2):

You have typos in the key names first 2 elements use `levelnumbers` but, last is `levelNumbers`. Also javascript does not have a `contains` function instead use the `indexOf` which returns `-1` if element is not present.

Comment: Firefox still retains `contains` but it's non-standard and not an option in most other environments. There is `includes`, however.